# Three dimensional pairing.

Tags: optimization, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Like in stable roommate problem we pair roommates together according to their preferences. If the problem is changed such that the ideal partner of each student is room dependent i.e. for room 1 the favorite partner of student A is student B but for room 2 the favorite partner of student A becomes some student D, where each student also has a room preference vector. Is there some technique to solve such problem? Which pair should be allocated which room and vice versa?